# Best Code Signing Practice

Tags: code-signing, digital-certificate

I have acquired and deployed a digital code signing certificate.  I have added it to the installation program for a Windows application, signing the InstallShield setup.exe file and the msi file.  Everything works perfectly in the installation program.

My application is installed as a single exe file along with a complied html help file.

Is the best practice to digitally sign the exe file in addition to the Windows installation program?

Comment: Why wouldn't you sign the installer? That's usually the first program the user will open and it would provide peace of mind knowing that its trusted.

Comment: Yes - sign both. The installer runs and is signed. Then the actual executable runs - and it is signed as well. Lots of trust to be gained - users know who made the code, and that it wasn't tampered with. I don't think your certificate "wears out"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You should sign the executable as well.

You should also ensure you use a time-stamp server if possible when signing too.  Thus users of your application know the code came from a valid source, and the certificate was valid when it was signed.  (The time-stamping means users can check the signing is valid after the expiry date of your certificate - i.e. the signature will be valid for all time.)